# What is standard practice to implement Push Notifications using Web-Push + Socket.io in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, push-notification, socket.io, web-push

I'm new to NodeJS and wondering about the best practice to implement Push Notification using Socket.IO and Web-Push library in NodeJS. Since Web-Push object can't be used inside **io.socket.on('connection', callback)** so this is what I'm thinking to do, is to store web-push endpoint in session corresponding to the user id and retrieve the endpoint inside socket scope to emit the data to the client.

Is this how it should be implemented? or what is the better way?

> NodeJS Function (at the node **server.js**) Responsible To Send Push Notification to Service-Worker Script

```
const sendWebPush = ( subscription, payload ) => {
  //webpush.sendNotification(socket.request.body, payload).catch(err => console.error(err));
  webpush.sendNotification( subscription, payload ).catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

> In this block I want to use the above function

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('join', function ( userID ) {
      // Pass object into sendNotification
        const payload = JSON.stringify({ title: "New Member Joined" });
        sendWebPush( socket.request.body, payload ); /* Unable to get the subscriber information through this piece of code socket.request.body */
        USERS[userID] = socket.id;
        io.emit('join',USERS);
    });
});
```

I just want to use this function inside socket callback. This is what i want to achieve.

Comment: why you think `socket.request.body` contains what you need? rtm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push

Comment: Yes, "socket.request.body" won't work here. How should i access request.body inside socket scope.

Comment: Is it possible to send the endpoint everytime during emit from the client then use endpoint(request.body) inside socket.io. Or storing endpoint in session corresponding to the user and retrieve(but in this case if a use logged in from multiple device then endpoint will get overwrite by new device endpoint and will leave push notification always work for a single device at a time.

Comment: I'm aware it can be achieved easily by putting in under route (express). But I am using Django for routes and using Node simply for selective features.